# Check if row of a certain id contains a specific number seperated by comma

Tags: php, mysql

What Am I doing wrong? As you can see, 139 is in row number 3. But still it returns false

```
id | babu | anum
--------------------    
1  | 76   | 34,21,421
2  | 76   | 345,948,21,433
3  | 76   | 634,35,11,65,139
4  | 76   | 4366,25,74,9


$a = $db->query("SELECT * FROM umaga WHERE babu = 76")->fetch();
$list_of_ids = explode(',', $a['anum']);

echo in_array(139, $list_of_ids)  ? 'ID 139 does exist in a row' : 'There is no row that contains that id';
```

Comment: NORMALIZE, NORMALIZE, NORMALIZE: What you're doing wrong is storing comma separated data in a table column.

Comment: If you really need to do this (and it is bad practise), then look at MySQL's [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function in your select statement

Answer (score 3):

I totally agree with others that you better normalize your data. But if for some reason that is not an option try to use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM umaga
 WHERE babu = 76
   AND FIND_IN_SET('139', anum) > 0
```

Output:

```
| ID | BABU |             ANUM |
--------------------------------
|  3 |   76 | 634,35,11,65,139 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20fdc/4)** demo

Now php code might look like

```php
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM umaga WHERE babu = 76 AND FIND_IN_SET('139', anum) > 0";
$result = $db->query($sql)->fetch();
echo $result ? 'ID 139 does exist in a row' : 'There is no row that contains that id';
```

Comment: Looks like an answer to me!

Answer (score 0):

### Never, never, never store multiple values in one column.

Like you see now this will only give you headaches. Normalize your table. Then you can select normally.

It should look like this

```
id | babu | anum
--------------------    
1  | 76   | 34
1  | 76   | 21
1  | 76   | 421
2  | 76   | 345
2  | 76   | 948
2  | 76   | 21
2  | 76   | 433
...
```

Comment: Why this is true, it doesn't answer the question. This bit on normalization would make a good side-note, but is not sufficiently an answer.

Comment: True - it is answerable. But I don't want to support doing that. And my answer answers the question: Change the DB structure and this problem will go away. That is what takes the problem at the source.

Comment: Technically it does answer the question, which was `What Am I doing wrong?`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to loop the result using `fetch` like

```
while($a = $db->query("SELECT * FROM umaga WHERE babu = 76")->fetch()){
$list_of_ids = explode(',', $a['anum']);

echo in_array(139, $list_of_ids)  ? 'ID 139 does exist in a row' : 'There is no row that contains that id';
}
```

As a side note, or should be main note, storing comma separated data is highly not recommended

Comment: A database query can be written such that not all rows are returned. This approach is extremely inefficient. Also, how does it differ from the original code?

Comment: it loops through the entire result set instead of just the last entry, come on?

Comment: Make it more obvious and also take time to format code so the intent is more readable. Otherwise, I agree that this answers the question of why the in-PHP version doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, but you should bring the echo `There is no row that contains` outside the loop (with some temp boolean variable) or change it in `This row does not contain` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

apart from the normalisation that is missing your query is fetching all rows from your database. you have to loop through them or use the ID in your where clause

Comment: You don't need to fetch all rows at all!

Comment: I didn't say he should. But that is what his script is doing at the moment.

Comment: Except it doesn't work: So why not? This doesn't say what is wrong at all (ignoring a denormalized model).